# Basic Use of Tmp-String-0

Tags: freeradius

I'm trying to use the Tmp-String-0 variable within a dhcp site enabled.

My version is old and in production (2.1.12).

Here is the content of my dhcp file.

```
dhcp DHCP-Discover {

    update control{
            Tmp-String-0 = "%{sql: CALL sqlprocedure('%{DHCP-Agent-Circuit-Id}','%{DHCP-Gateway-IP-Address}','%{DHCP-Relay-Remote-Id}')}"
    }

    if(control:Tmp-String-0 != "" ) {
            update reply {
                    DHCP-Message-Type = DHCP-Offer
            }
    }
    else {
            update reply {
                    DHCP-Message-Type = DHCP-NAK
            }
    }

update reply {
DHCP-Your-IP-Address = "control:Tmp-String-0"
}
}
```

And here is the result I have in debug mode.

```
rlm_sql_mysql: query:   CALL sqlprocedure('value','1.2.3.4','value')
sql_xlat finished
rlm_sql (sql): Released sql socket id: 4
expand: %{sql: CALL sqlprocedure('%{DHCP-Agent-Circuit-Id}','%{DHCP-Gateway-IP-Address}','%{DHCP-Relay-Remote-Id}')} -> 10.10.10.10
++[control] returns noop
++? if (control:Tmp-String-0 != "" )
? Evaluating (control:Tmp-String-0 != "" ) -> TRUE
++? if (control:Tmp-String-0 != "" ) -> TRUE
++- entering if (control:Tmp-String-0 != "" ) {...}
+++[reply] returns noop
++- if (control:Tmp-String-0 != "" ) returns noop
++ ... skipping else for request 445: Preceding "if" was taken
ERROR: Failed parsing value "control:Tmp-String-0" for attribute DHCP-Your- 
IP-Address: Failed to find IP address for control:Tmp-String-0
++[reply] returns fail
```

I don't know what is wrong with that maybe I should use the operator "=" instead of ":=".

What do you think?

Many thanks, Will

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following

```
update reply {
DHCP-Your-IP-Address = "Tmp-String-0"
}
```